# php/javascript change inline label after DB update

Tags: javascript, php, onclick, label, updating

this is my first post.. my question probably is very simple but i cannot find the right way..!

I have a php page with a query selection from a database to show many records, for each record i've put form with some fields need to be updated and a "save" button

so for each record i have a column in the result table containing a form like:

```
$code = "<td><form method='POST' action='mypage.php' target='_blank' />";

$code .= " <input type='hidden' name='function' value='formtaglieok' />";
$code .= " <input type='hidden' name='email' value='".$email."' />";
$code .= " <input type='hidden' name='main' value='".$main."' />";
..... some other editing fields
$code .= "<input type='text' name='field1' value='' size='2' />"
..... some other editing fields
$code .= "<td><input type='submit' value='Save' /></td>"
```

after this column i've put label that i want to change after pressing the button and the updating of the record, like:

```
$code .= "<td><div id='<this_record_id>' ></div></td>";
```

in mypage.php i have the php code to update the record:

```
function updaterecord($_POST){
  ...connection to db, prepare the query etc..
  $stid = OCIParse($conn, $query);        

  if (OCIExecute($stid)) {
      $res .= "Saved ";
  } else {
      $res .= "Error";      
  } 

  echo $res;     
}
```

obviously, with this kind of form action and the target "_blank", i see in a new page the result "Saved" or "Error" and the updating of the record in DB is ok

The thing i would is not put "Saved" in a new page, but update the div **this_record_id** beside the "save" button

so, i'll try to add the onClick event to the submit button

```
<input type='submit' value='Save' onclick='jSaved(<this_record_id>)' />
```

and put this code in the head of the page

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function jSaved(bcode){

    document.getElementById(bcode).innerHTML = 'Saved';
}
</script>
```

and it updating the label correctly but opening also another page.

what i would to do is executing my updating function inside the JS code using the $_POST array, so don't get a new page but only the result of the function in the label..

someone can help me?

**edit: SOLVED**

1) my php main page with a form like (IMPORTANT set the form_id):

```
$code = "<form name='frm_".$record['TD001_SEQ']."' id='frm_".$record['TD001_SEQ']."' action='' />";

$code .= " <input type='hidden' name='function'  id='function' value='formtaglieok' />";


$code .= " <input type='hidden' name='email'     id='email' value='".$email."' />";
$code .= " <input type='hidden' name='main'      id='main' value='".$main."' />";
$code .= " <input type='hidden' name='store'     id='store' value='".$store."' />";
$code .= " <input type='hidden' name='valuta'    id='valuta' value='".$valuta."' />";
....other fields
//the code for the button (not submit)
$code .= "<td><input type='button' value='Save' onclick='jSaved(".$record['TD001_SEQ']."); '/></td>";
//the label DIV with the same reference of the form/record updating
$code .= "<td><div id='res_".$record['TD001_SEQ']."' ></div></td>";
```

2) the javascript code

```
  function jSaved(td001){

        //searching for exact form from the document page
        var form = false;
    var length = document.forms.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      if(document.forms[i].id == "frm_" + td001) {
        form = document.forms[i];
      }
    }

    //create a string containing all key/values from the form (parameters)      
        length = form.length;
        var sParams = "";

        for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          //will be key1=val1&key2=val2 ....
          sParams = sParams + form.elements[i].id + "=" + form.elements[i].value + "&";

    }

    //execute the php update function with params in POST, td001 is needed to write le DIV label after update       

        var updResult = updateRecord("upd.php", sParams, td001);


  }

    //ajax code
  function updateRecord(strUrl, params, idDiv) {
    var xmlHttpReq = false;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
      else if (window.ActiveXObject) {

      xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }


    xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strUrl, true);


    xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');


    xmlHttpReq.send(params);


    xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {

        /*state evaluation
        * 0 - UNINITIALIZED
        * 1 - LOADING
        * 2 - LOADED
        * 3 - INTERACTIVE
        * 4 - COMPLETE*/

        //state complete
        if (xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
                //updating the DIV label with upd.php result 
                document.getElementById('res_' + idDiv).innerHTML = xmlHttpReq.responseText;
        } 


    }

    return resUpd;
  }


</script>
```

3) the upd.php page

```
if (isset($_POST)) {      
  funFormTaglieOK($_POST);
} else {
  echo "Denied";
}

function funFormTaglieOK($params){
  global $dbdw_usr, $dbdw_pwd, $dbdw_SID;
    // Try to connect to Oracle
  if ($conn = OCILogon($dbdw_usr, $dbdw_pwd, $dbdw_SID)) {
   //execute record update
   if (recordupdate is ok){
    echo "Update"
   } else {
    echo "Error" 
   }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you should use ajax, and don't use target=_blank.

If you want a new window, you can still open that by Javascript.

In Your PHP code which is called by an ajax call, you should return the right results in a JSON format. You have to parse that string in JS, and do your DOM update accordingly.

Comment: Thanks SalDev for your prompt reply, but probably i didn't explain my problem correctly, the function as described, at the moment do 2 things separately: 1 is the php called by the "action" in form and update the record but show me the response in a separate window, 2 in the onclick event that show me "saved" where i need. What i want is launch the record update from the onclick event, that will show in the DIV element the right response (not in a separate window), so i need to know hot to use the $_POST of the form from the JS code, thanks..

Comment: yes, removing the target _blank i don't have a new page, but the main page with all records extracted will be now recreated and is not what i need.. The main page with all resultset should be always the same, and pressing the single Update button for each record, only the DIV label should be updated with the indication "saved" beside the record, so the onClick JS function should be execute the php code for the record updating, without open a new page or recreating the existing one, only getting the result of the operation and put it in the label, i hope is clear

Comment: Yes, that is why i was recommending you to use ajax. You could send one dataset per ajax request, and update the exact DIV with the result of the server-side operation. You don't have to rebuild any part of the DOM, just update the appropriate DIV's innerHTML value with the result text.

Comment: Thanks SalDev, my problem is that i am a "vintage" programmer and just now i'm reading about AJAX.. but i found a link with an example that help me to understand what is exactly the AJAX and this code helped me: http://www.danieletabacco.com/un-semplice-esempio-di-ajax/